# Find words with most occurrence of each letter in the alphabet

Tags: java, arrays, iterator

I've written a program to read from a text file where each line is a word. The first portion of code finds the longest word beginning with each letter of the alphabet and stores it in an array. The 2nd part I want the program to do is find, for each letter of the alphabet, the word with the highest occurrence of that letter.

So the output SHOULD look like this:

Longest words:

```
a: anthropomorphologically
b: blepharosphincterectomy
c: cholecystenterorrhaphy
d: dacryocystoblennorrhea
e: epididymodeferentectomy
f: formaldehydesulphoxylate
g: gastroenteroanastomosis
h: hematospectrophotometer
i: indistinguishableness
j: jurisprudentialist
k: keratoconjunctivitis
l: laparocolpohysterotomy
m: macracanthrorhynchiasis
n: naphthylaminesulphonic
o: omnirepresentativeness
p: pathologicopsychological
q: quadratomandibular
r: reticulatocoalescent
s: scientificophilosophical
t: tetraiodophenolphthalein
u: ureterocystanastomosis
v: vagoglossopharyngeal
w: weatherproofness
x: xanthocreatinine
y: yohimbinization
z: zoologicoarchaeologist
```

---

Words with most letter:

```
a: astragalocalcaneal
b: beblubber
c: chlorococcaceae
d: disdodecahedroid
e: electrotelethermometer
f: giffgaff
g: cuggermugger
h: choledochorrhaphy
i: impossibilification
j: ajaja
k: akiskemikinik
l: allochlorophyll
m: dynamometamorphism
n: nonannouncement
o: choledochoduodenostomy
p: aplopappus
q: equivoque
r: archcorrupter
s: possessionlessness
t: anticonstitutionalist
u: untumultuous
v: overconservative
w: bowwow
x: adnexopexy
y: dacryocystosyringotomy
z: zizz
```

}

Basically, I need to figure out how to do it so the output isn't the word with the most letters same as the first letter (like how 'f' [giffgaff] above does not begin with 'f'). I've googled/bing'd a lot and not found anything to help.

```
/**
 * @param args first String argument is the
 *        name of the input text file
 */
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {

    //instance variable
    String[] longestWords = new String[26];
    String[] mostCharsWord = new String[26];
    String currentLine = null;

    int[] numCharacters = new int[26];

    //because the while loop in try statement is comparing lengths in order to
    //assign words, I must give each element a non-null value
    //in this case, length = 0
    Arrays.fill(longestWords, "");
    Arrays.fill(mostCharsWord, "");

    //try block
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]))) {
        String currentLongestWord;
        int index;
        int indexer = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int counter = 0;

        while((currentLine=br.readLine()) != null) {
            currentLine = currentLine.toLowerCase();
            index = currentLine.charAt(0)-'a';
            currentLongestWord = longestWords[index];
            if(currentLine.length() > currentLongestWord.length()) {
                longestWords[index] = currentLine;
            }

            /**
             * this code below is for the "AND" bit, but I know that it's not correct.
             * Instead of printing out the word with the most occurrences of each
             * letter, it prints out the word with the most occurrences of each letter
             * THAT BEGINS WITH THAT LETTER
             */

            for(char c : currentLine.toCharArray()) {
                if(c == currentLine.charAt(0)) {
                    count += 1;
                }
            }

            for(String currentMostCharsWord : mostCharsWord) {
                indexer += 1;
                for(char c : currentLine.toCharArray()) {
                    for( char d: currentMostCharsWord.toCharArray()) {
                        if(c==d) {
                            //hmmm....this would compare every letter, not just the one
                            //that I'm looking for. booooooo
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(count > numCharacters[index]) {
                numCharacters[index] = count;
                mostCharsWord[index] = currentLine;
            }

            count = 0;
        }

        //close file!
        br.close();
    }

    //catch block
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //finally / do anyway statement
    finally {
        System.out.println("Longest Words: \n");
        for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%s: %s\n", longestWords[j].charAt(0), longestWords[j]);
        }

        System.out.println("------------------------------------\n\nWords with most letters: \n");
        for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%s: %s\n", mostCharsWord[j].charAt(0), mostCharsWord[j]);
        }
    }   
}
```

}

Comment: Try to break down your question into something a little more simple. Asking the community to solve an entire puzzle is less likely to produce an answer than asking them which puzzle piece goes 'here'.

Comment: @Okuma.Scott Sorry, this is my first time actually asking a question on here and I just wanted to include as much information as possible. I thought I was closer to the answer than I actually was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use something like this:

```
// Map with the longest word for each letter
Map<Character, String> longestWordMap = new HashMap<Character, String>();
// Map with the word with highest occurrences of each letter
Map<Character, String> mostCharsWordMap = new HashMap<Character, String>();

while((word = br.readLine()) != null) { {
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    Character beginning = word.charAt(0);
    String longestWord = longestWordMap.get(beginning);
    // If the current word is the longest, put the word in the map
    if (longestWord == null || word.length() > longestWord.length()) {
            longestWordMap.put(beginning, word);
    }
    for (char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++) {
        String mostCharsWord = mostCharsWordMap.get(Character.valueOf(letter));
        if (mostCharsWord == null || 
            characterCount(letter, word) > characterCount(letter, mostCharsWord)) {
            mostCharsWordMap.put(Character.valueOf(letter), word);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the function used to count the occurrences of a letter in a word:

```
public static int characterCount(char letter, String word) {
    int characterCount = 0;
    for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == letter) {
            characterCount++;
        }
    }
    return characterCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more straight-forward approach to this.  So the problem is in essence that you have a stream of words and based on the word that is currently being read from the stream you compare it against the longest known word you have in your data store.  If it is longer you replace the word, else do nothing.  Your logic may be to replace it based on something else, such as dictionary ordering of the word.  Checking for case sensitivity is left as an exercise to you.

//mostly pseudo-code

```
public class LongestWord  
{  
    Map<Character,String> longestWords = new HashMap<Character,String>();  

    while(wordsStream.hasNext())  
    {    
         String currentWord = wordStream.next();  
         String longestWordByLetter = longestWords.get(currentWord.charAt(0));  
         if(null != longestWordByLetter)  
         {   
            if(longestWordByLetter.size() < currentWord.size())  
            {  
                 longestWords.put(currentWord.charAt(0),currentWord);
            }//else do nothing      
         }else{  
              longestWords.put(currentWord.charAt(0),currentWord);  
         }  
    }  

}
```